# How to delete all &#65279; via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode, google-chrome-extension, zero-width-space

I've made an extension for google Chrome, it's a Bot for the Supreme Shop. 
The Bot worked nearly one year. But now Supreme changed their Product names. Example: before "Supreme®/Hanes® Tagless Tees (3 Pack)" and now they put randomly some &#65279 (Zero Width No-Break Space) in the Name. I've tried to delete this with ** product_color = product_color.replace(/&#,65279;/g, '');** But this is not really working. Does anybody has an idea..

ps: there's no colon in my code. But else it would like this in the post //

thanks alot

Comment: You can use Unicode in Regex with `\uFEFF`. I.e. `product_color = product_color.replace(/\uFEFF/g,"");`.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko could you expalin a bit more? I'm using the product name to compare with my keywords and if they fit the bot takes it and if there are some unicode symbols they dont match

Comment: @IvánNokonoko: My mistake, it isn't *(an invalid Unicode escape sequence, as my deleted comment said; I thought it would require a surrogate pair, but it doesn't)*. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @YanikEmmenegger: `&#65279;` is just a numeric character reference for character U+FEFF. When the browser parses the HTML, it turns that into the relevant character. In JavaScript, you can write that same character as `\uFEFF`, and so you can replace it as shown in his comment above.

Comment: Thanks it works @IvánNokonoko

Comment: Thanks it works @T.J.Crowder